# Get value from threaded method

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm trying to access a database, get an image and return it so it then can be shown in a Border object. (So I'm converting the byte[] data to an image, too)
This process takes enough time to notice that the UI has frozen.

Here's some code:

```
ImageBrush imgb = new ImageBrush();
imgb.ImageSource = GlobalDB.GetImage(album.name, 400); // Size is 400px, this is the time-consuming part.
AlbumArt.Background = imgb;
```

I tried using a backgroundworker but that gave me an exception saying I can't call from different threads. I got that exception since the BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted apparently was owned by a different thread(?)

Adding to that last bit: the Runworkercompleted did this:

```
AlbumArt.Background = imgb;
```

I now don't know what to do.
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to ask.  Where is your view model?  Rohit Vats's answer will more or less get the job done, **but** you are not approaching this idiomatically.  You should have a ViewModel with code something like this:

```
public class AlbumViewModel: BaseViewModel // BaseViewModel is your code that implements INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string name
public string Name
{
   get{ return name;}
   set
   {
      if(name != value)
      {
          name = value;
          FirePropertyChanged("Name");
          LoadBackgroundImageAsync(value);
      }
   }

}

private ImageSource backgroundImage;
public ImageSource BackgroundImage
{
     get{return backgroundImage;}
     private set
     {
       if(backgroundImage != value)
       {
           background = value;
           FirePropertyChanged("BackgroundImage");
       }
     }
}
private Task LoadBackgroundImageAsync(string name)
{
    var retv = new Task(()=>
    {
        var source = GlobalDB.GetImage(name, 400);
        source.Freeze();
        BackgroundImage = source;
    });
    retv.Start();
    return retv;
}
}
```

Then just bind to the property and let WPF wory about updating the UI.

Comment: I feel like I've missed out on quite a bit here. Since I've only been learning by doing. Think I have to read up on this stuff before I make any more unnecessary things like this with Databinding. Thanks for this great answer though! Looks like there's a few things to read up on.

Answer (score 4):

`RunWorkerCompleted` gets called on UI thread only.

Only issue i can see in your code is **`imgb` is created in background thread** and WPF has constraint that ***DependencyProperty source and Dependency object should be created on same thread.***

So before assigning imgb to Background call `Freeze()` on it:

```
imgb.Freeze();
AlbumArt.Background = imgb;
```

Reason being **`freezed objects are allowed to be access across threads`**. They are not thread affine.

Comment: this is correct with the caveat that this only works with .net 4+, in 3.5 you have to marshal the update to the UI thread yourself.

Comment: @Yaur - That's not true. That's how background worker is implemented from start irrespective of .Net versions. `BackgroundWoker captures the SynchronizationContext when RunWorkerAsync is called. It then uses that captured SynchronizationContext to execute RunWorkerCompleted.` So, if you call RunWorkerAsync from UI thread then RunWorkerCompleted will be called on UI thread only.

Comment: If you are messing with the view properties directly (which you really shouldn't do) then you always have to worry about marshaling to the UI thread.  `BackgroundWorker` is one way to do that... though it is not mentioned in your answer and there is no context in which the code you have is going to be valid on consecutive lines assuming that the image source is created on a background thread.  leaving my +1 anyway since the crux of what the OP is missing is the call to Freeze.

Comment: Both of your statements are contradictory. first you said BW won't work with version 3.5 and lower. now you said BW is a way to Marshall back stuff on UI thread which is wrong(that's why not mentioned in answer). Also didnt mentioned to get image in DoWork handler of BW since OP is already aware of it as he mentioned in his question. Anyways let's put an end to this if OP has understood the issue in his code. And thanks for +1. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

not sure about what GetImage are doing, but maybe you can enclosure your code into a Task:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    ImageBrush imgb = new ImageBrush();
    imgb.ImageSource = GlobalDB.GetImage(album.name, 400);
    AlbumArt.Background = imgb;
});
```

Comment: This won't work because `AlbumArt.Background` can't be accessed from the task thread. You would have to dispatch the assignment to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in another answer, you may alternatively use an asynchronous task. But you have to dispatch the assignment of the `Background` property to the UI thread after freezing the ImageBrush.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var imgb = new ImageBrush(GlobalDB.GetImage(album.name, 400));
    imgb.Freeze();

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => AlbumArt.Background = imgb));
});
```